# xcode to auto create folder if doesn't exists

Tags: iphone, xcode, directory

Just wondering if xCode is able to auto create a folder in desktop if it doesn't exists?

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/Users/admin/Desktop/12Dec2012";
```

assuming that folder '12Dec2012' is not created on desktop but i wish to save a .txt to folder '12Dec2012' , will xCode auto create the folder and store the .txt file it in?

Answer (score 9):

No, it won't be created. Use this to create folders:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/admin/Desktop/12Dec2012/"
                        isDirectory:YES];

NSError *createError = nil;
BOOL success = [manager createDirectoryAtURL:url
                 withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                  attributes:nil
                                       error:&createError];

if (!success) {
    // Handle error
    return;
}

// Use folder
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to check to see if the directory exists and create it if not.